# Find and update email in file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh, ksh

I have input plan text file and i should change from **%first_name%.%last_name%@my.com** to **first.lastname_%sequence%@my.com**

can anyone help me?

```
input file:
column1,column2,column3,jack.jack@my.com,column5
column1,column2,column3,tom.tom@my.com,column5
column1,column2,column3,mike.mike@my.com,column5
column1,column2,column3,albert.albert@my.com,column5

output file:
column1,column2,column3,first.lastname_1@my.com,column5
column1,column2,column3,first.lastname_2@my.com,column5
column1,column2,column3,first.lastname_3@my.com,column5
column1,column2,column3,first.lastname_4@my.com,column5
```

Comment: Your input and output aren't consistent and you haven't made any effort to solve this problem yourself. Please [edit] your question to improve it and see [ask] for some general pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for something like this:

```
count=1
for line in `cat <your_input_file>`; do
    echo $line | sed -r "s/,[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@my.com,/,first.lastname_$count@my.com,/"
    count=`expr $count + 1`
done
```

Comment: thank you, but i shold get for jack.jack@my.com -> first.lastname_1@my.com and tom.tom@my.com -> first.lastname_2@my.com ...,